# Create histogram given start and end values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with "start" and "end" columns: for the sake of simplicity, let's assume they are integers between 1 and 10. I would like to somehow obtain a histogram of the values between "start" and "end".

For instance, given the following rows:

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 9 |

I would like to obtain the following histogram:

| time | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 |

I really have no idea where to start looking in the SQL syntax to get that result -- maybe an inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate times -- if you don't have a handy tally or numbers table.  Then join and aggregate:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select 1 as t
      union all
      select t + 1
      from cte
      where t < 10
     )
select cte.t,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where cte.t between t.start and t.end
       ) as cnt
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=998edd9fe91163917044c75368b4498c) is a db<>fiddle.